# How to use a LINQ where clause on a list of Func delegates

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, delegates

I'm trying to build an in-process pub-subscriber pattern within a particular channel. All the callee would have to do is to call the channel.Post(new RetrieveRecords()) and the registered handlers would of course handle the specific message.

Therefore, I have a list of handlers of type Func and when I query the list, I'd like to return only the handlers that accept a specific type.

I know I could create a Handler class that included the type of T and the Func as properties, but I was hoping there was a more elegant way to resolve.

```cs
protected List<Func<object, IMessage>> Handlers { get; } = new List<Func<object, IMessage>>();

public Task Post(IMessage message, Action<IMessage> callback = null)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var hands = Handlers.Where(h => h()) <== I don't know what to do here
    });
}

public Task Register<T>(Func<T, IMessage> handler) where T : IMessage
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Handlers.Add(a => handler((T)a));
    });
}
```

I was thinking that I would use message.GetType() in the Post method if casting in the where clause isn't possible.

Comment: Do you mean *"only the handlers that **accept** a specific type"*?

Comment: Indeed- thanks for the clarifying question.

Comment: And which type's handler do you want to find? `Post` doesn't have a type argument or accept a `Type` parameter.

Comment: I was thinking that I would use IMessage message.GetType().  If that isn't possible, I could certainly add a type parameter to Post

Comment: Is it an option to have List<Delegate>? And then in where you can check if delegate has type you need.

Comment: You should include that in the question. It's not exactly impossible per se; it informs other parts of your design. For example, you *really* need `where T : IMessage` on your `Register` method for that to work.

Comment: Viktor, I think I'm tracking, but how would you check for type in Delegate?

Comment: Still trying to drill in on what you're trying to do here... let's say you use `message.GetType()` and filter the handlers to those that accept that type, `Post` passes `message` to the handler in the first parameter as the concrete type (we'll figure that out later). How would it return an `IMessage`?  Would it return itself? Can you include an example usage of your `Post` method and an example class that implements `IMessage`?

Comment: Then if you know the type in compile-time could be e.g. var handlers = Handlers.OfType<Func<TArg, IMessage>>();

Comment: You *could* change your handlers to be `Func<IMessage, IMessage>` since all your messages will have to implement `IMessage`. However, that means that your handler search will have to look at the *invocation list* to test the parameter type since the delegate instance will not have type information. You shouldn't have to deal with the invocation list, though. That's a bad idea.

Comment: Can you please explain more about what you are trying to do instead of how you are trying to solve it? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Jota, I'm trying to build an in-process pub-subscriber pattern within a particular channel.  All the callee would have to do is to call the channel.Post(new RetrieveRecords()) and the registered handlers would of course handle the specific message.

Comment: Update your question with the relevant comments please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't initially see that you were wrapping the handler in a call to a less specific lambda instance.  That actually hides the type information you need for the filter.  Viktor's right about the list element type.  You need to add the handler instance directly, which requires a less specific delegate type (indeed, the least specific).

```cs
protected List<Delegate> Handlers { get; } = new List<Delegate>();
```

You don't need to fire off a background task to register the handler.  The operation isn't I/O-bound so `Register` can simply add the instance to the list.

```cs
public void Register<T>(Func<T, IMessage> handler)
    where T : IMessage
{
    Handlers.Add(handler);
}
```

You indicated that you want to use `message.GetType()` to get the type for the handlers you want to call.

```cs
Type handlerArgumentType = message.GetType();
```

To test the handler, you need to get the type of the first argument and compare it to `handlerArgumentType`.  Because `Register<T>` requires a `Func<T, IMessage>`, you know that you'll have **2** type arguments, so you can index the array returned by `GetGenericArguments` without doing a length check first.

```cs
var handlers = Handlers.Where(h => h.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == handlerArgumentType);
```

Here's where it gets tricky: *calling* the handler.  Because the only static type information you
have is that of the ancestor `Delegate` class, you have to "springboard" to something that can cast it to the right type and call it.  *(This is an expression-bodied method in the final code below.)*

```cs
private static IMessage CallHandler<T>(Delegate del, T input)
{
    return ((Func<T, IMessage>)del)(input);
}
```

With that springboard method, you can use reflection to find and invoke a close-constructed `MethodInfo` for each handler.

```cs
foreach (var handler in handlers)
{
    IMessage result = (IMessage)GetType()
        .GetMethod(nameof(CallHandler), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
        .MakeGenericMethod(handlerArgumentType)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { handler, message });
}
```

Now that I've explained it in parts, here's the whole thing:

```cs
protected List<Delegate> Handlers { get; } = new List<Delegate>();

public Task Post(IMessage message, Action<IMessage> callback = null)
{
    if (message is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));

    var handlerArgumentType = message.GetType();

    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //var hands = Handlers.Where(h => h()) <== I don't know what to do here
        var handlers = Handlers.Where(h => h.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == handlerArgumentType);
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            IMessage result = (IMessage)GetType()
                .GetMethod(nameof(CallHandler), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                .MakeGenericMethod(handlerArgumentType)
                .Invoke(null, new object[] { handler, message });
        }
    });
}

private static IMessage CallHandler<T>(Delegate del, T input) => ((Func<T, IMessage>)del)(input);

public void Register<T>(Func<T, IMessage> handler)
    where T : IMessage
{
    Handlers.Add(handler);
}
```

*Note: Instead of throwing `ArgumentNullException`, you could use `message?.GetType()` and let the `null` that it returns match nothing.  Which way you choose to handle it depends on whether passing `null` is a valid thing to do.*

Now, I believe the only remaining question is what to do with the callback.  Maybe pass `result` to it?

```cs
callback?.Invoke(result);
```

---

**Final Note:** This should work, given what you've provided.  However, it's definitely not the best implementation.  Calling `Invoke` frequently because `Post` is called frequently, or you have lots of handlers for a single type to call in the loop, could take up quite some time (relatively speaking).  Now that you have something that works, you can refactor it, whether that's now or whenever you observe degrading performance.  You should at least *think* about it now so you're not panicking later on.